# What package is used with \up in beamer

Tags: math-mode, packages

I am using `k\up{ème}` in beamer. It does not work. I think that It lack some package.

Description of `k\up{ème}`: `ème` should be up of `k`

See my preamble:

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{multicol}
   \usepackage{animate}
    \usepackage{movie15}
   \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{epsfig}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
   \xyoption{arc}
    \usepackage{url}
       \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
      %\usepackage{multimedia}
      \usepackage{hyperref}
         \usepackage{setspace}
           \usepackage{multirow} 
    %--------------------------------------------------
       %How to show covered parts using overlay.
       %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
       %\useoutertheme{infolines}
           %\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
       %\setlength{\textwidth}{1\textheight}%
          %}{}
          \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
                 \setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\tiny}
                  \setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\tiny}
             \setbeamerfont{block title example}{size=\tiny}
              \setbeamerfont{block body example}{size=\tiny}
             \setbeamerfont{alertblock title }{size=\tiny}
            \setbeamerfont{alertblock body }{size=\tiny}
            \usepackage{times}
```

Comment: Please add an MWE (Minimal (Non)Working Example), beginning with `\documentclass{beamer}` and ending with `\end{document}`. One Beamer frame is enough, with a complete preamble (but nothing irrelevant to the question).

Comment: Commands such as `\ieme` exist, using the `french` pilot of the `babel` package. They should solve your problem even better that redefining the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is this. Add this to your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\up}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

Comment: You've answered sooner than he finally answered what does `\up` do... ebből nem okul... :)

Comment: @masu, I have already fix the problem by adding \usepackage[french,english]{babel}

Comment: @phdstudent the misunderstanding was caused by the fact that you knew you're French, and we did not, and `\up` is a common macro in French text (I suppose, if `babel` has it).